# Cannot get CMV / Disclaimer Widget up and running

Tags: windows, configurable-map-viewer

I am a Noob to javascript so forgive my ignorance.

I have moved all folders and associated files from the download to the CMV Dijit folder with exception of the config file which I placed in the config folder.

Do I need to modify any existing script to get this thing running? 
Does it run "out of the box" like the actual CMV app?

I am running Windows OS.

Comment: Welcome! Could you please include information about your system? Windows, Mac or Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That all sounds correct except perhaps the last sentence.  Did you make that change in your applications config file `viewer.js` or in `disclaimer.js`? You should not copy the disclaimer.js file as that is just an example.

You should be making changes in viewer.js since that is the file used by your application. There won't be a disclaimer widget configuration in your standard viewer.js so you'll have to copy that widget configuration into your  own file.

Comment: No I had copied the disclaimer.js config file and pasted that in the config folder as well as changed the path in that disclaimer.js file. Where in the viewer.js do I need to change this path?

Comment: The viewer.js file should have already been in the config folder before you started to add the disclaimer widget.  If it is not there, then maybe you did not have function

Comment: sorry - On phone.  Start with a clean functioning cmv app.  Only then would you add the disclaimer widget to that app following the steps I described. .

Comment: This was a clean install ..... The viewer.js file is in the config folder of my app

Comment: OK. That is the file I was referring to that you need to modify. You will add the disclaimer widget to widgets section of that file along with the others. You can get the few lines of configuration from the disclaimer.js example file or copy it from this example:  https://github.com/tmcgee/cmv-widgets/tree/master/widgets/Disclaimer#example-configuration

Comment: I hate not understanding .... So that example of the config file disclaimer.js ... copy that and then paste that script in the viewer.js config file? You have the patience of Job my friend

Comment: I'm going to add another separate answer with this complete configuration listed because comments are limited in length. It will be the initial cmv viewer.js with the disclaimer widget added.

Comment: Not everyone is as clueless as me though ;) Thanks again Tim ..... Much appriciated

Comment: If the final answer helped solve this for you, can you please mark it as answered to help others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to move the entire config file.  You should copy the disclaimer widget's configuration from the `widgets` section in that file to the `widgets` section of your own application's config file.  Make sure the `path` property correctly points to `gis/dijit/Disclaimer` like your other widgets.

If you are using the href property, make sure it references the location where the disclaimer.html page is located. Something like `config/disclaimer.html`.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response Tim!! Still no luck though.I must be missing something? I'll try and be more specific. When I download your zip file, I open the folder which contains multiple folders and files. cmv, config, css, images, widgets, index.html, demo.html, readme.md. I open the config folder and copy the disclaimer.js and disclaimer.html files and paste them in my config folder within my app. I open the widgets folder and copy the Disclaimer folder and Disclaimer.js file and paste them in my gis/digits folder in my app. I have also changed path in config to gis/dijit/Disclaimer

Answer (score 0):

Below is a complete `config/viewer.js` configuration with the disclaimer widget added (11 lines of code) at the very bottom. It refers to the file disclaimer.html which should also be in the config folder.

```
define([
   'esri/units',
   'esri/geometry/Extent',
   'esri/config',
   'esri/tasks/GeometryService',
   'esri/layers/ImageParameters'
], function (units, Extent, esriConfig, GeometryService, ImageParameters) {

    // url to your proxy page, must be on same machine hosting you app. See proxy folder for readme.
    esriConfig.defaults.io.proxyUrl = 'proxy/proxy.ashx';
    esriConfig.defaults.io.alwaysUseProxy = false;
    // url to your geometry server.
    esriConfig.defaults.geometryService = new GeometryService('http://tasks.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer');

    //image parameters for dynamic services, set to png32 for higher quality exports.
    var imageParameters = new ImageParameters();
    imageParameters.format = 'png32';

    return {
        // used for debugging your app
        isDebug: true,

        //default mapClick mode, mapClickMode lets widgets know what mode the map is in to avoid multipult map click actions from taking place (ie identify while drawing).
        defaultMapClickMode: 'identify',
        // map options, passed to map constructor. see: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/map-amd.html#map1
        mapOptions: {
            basemap: 'streets',
            center: [-96.59179687497497, 39.09596293629694],
            zoom: 5,
            sliderStyle: 'small'
        },
        // panes: {
        //  left: {
        //      splitter: true
        //  },
        //  right: {
        //      id: 'sidebarRight',
        //      placeAt: 'outer',
        //      region: 'right',
        //      splitter: true,
        //      collapsible: true
        //  },
        //  bottom: {
        //      id: 'sidebarBottom',
        //      placeAt: 'outer',
        //      splitter: true,
        //      collapsible: true,
        //      region: 'bottom'
        //  },
        //  top: {
        //      id: 'sidebarTop',
        //      placeAt: 'outer',
        //      collapsible: true,
        //      splitter: true,
        //      region: 'top'
        //  }
        // },
        // collapseButtonsPane: 'center', //center or outer

        // operationalLayers: Array of Layers to load on top of the basemap: valid 'type' options: 'dynamic', 'tiled', 'feature'.
        // The 'options' object is passed as the layers options for constructor. Title will be used in the legend only. id's must be unique and have no spaces.
        // 3 'mode' options: MODE_SNAPSHOT = 0, MODE_ONDEMAND = 1, MODE_SELECTION = 2
        operationalLayers: [{
            type: 'feature',
            url: 'http://services1.arcgis.com/g2TonOxuRkIqSOFx/arcgis/rest/services/MeetUpHomeTowns/FeatureServer/0',
            title: 'STLJS Meetup Home Towns',
            options: {
                id: 'meetupHometowns',
                opacity: 1.0,
                visible: true,
                outFields: ['*'],
                mode: 0
            },
            editorLayerInfos: {
                disableGeometryUpdate: false
            }
  }, {
            type: 'feature',
            url: 'http://sampleserver3.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/SanFrancisco/311Incidents/FeatureServer/0',
            title: 'San Francisco 311 Incidents',
            options: {
                id: 'sf311Incidents',
                opacity: 1.0,
                visible: true,
                outFields: ['req_type', 'req_date', 'req_time', 'address', 'district'],
                mode: 0
            }
  }, {
            type: 'dynamic',
            url: 'http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/PublicSafety/PublicSafetyOperationalLayers/MapServer',
            title: 'Louisville Public Safety',
            options: {
                id: 'louisvillePubSafety',
                opacity: 1.0,
                visible: true,
                imageParameters: imageParameters
            },
            identifyLayerInfos: {
                layerIds: [2, 4, 5, 8, 12, 21]
            }
  }, {
            type: 'dynamic',
            url: 'http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/DamageAssessment/MapServer',
            title: 'Damage Assessment',
            options: {
                id: 'DamageAssessment',
                opacity: 1.0,
                visible: true,
                imageParameters: imageParameters
            },
            layerControlLayerInfos: {
                swipe: true,
                metadataUrl: true,
                expanded: true
            }
  }],
        // set include:true to load. For titlePane type set position the the desired order in the sidebar
        widgets: {
            growler: {
                include: true,
                id: 'growler',
                type: 'domNode',
                path: 'gis/dijit/Growler',
                srcNodeRef: 'growlerDijit',
                options: {}
            },
            geocoder: {
                include: true,
                id: 'geocoder',
                type: 'domNode',
                path: 'gis/dijit/Geocoder',
                srcNodeRef: 'geocodeDijit',
                options: {
                    map: true,
                    mapRightClickMenu: true,
                    geocoderOptions: {
                        autoComplete: true,
                        arcgisGeocoder: {
                            placeholder: 'Enter an address or place'
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            identify: {
                include: true,
                id: 'identify',
                type: 'titlePane',
                path: 'gis/dijit/Identify',
                title: 'Identify',
                open: false,
                position: 3,
                options: 'config/identify'
            },
            basemaps: {
                include: true,
                id: 'basemaps',
                type: 'domNode',
                path: 'gis/dijit/Basemaps',
                srcNodeRef: 'basemapsDijit',
                options: 'config/basemaps'
            },
            mapInfo: {
                include: false,
                id: 'mapInfo',
                type: 'domNode',
                path: 'gis/dijit/MapInfo',
                srcNodeRef: 'mapInfoDijit',
                options: {
                    map: true,
                    mode: 'dms',
                    firstCoord: 'y',
                    unitScale: 3,
                    showScale: true,
                    xLabel: '',
                    yLabel: '',
                    minWidth: 286
                }
            },
            scalebar: {
                include: true,
                id: 'scalebar',
                type: 'map',
                path: 'esri/dijit/Scalebar',
                options: {
                    map: true,
                    attachTo: 'bottom-left',
                    scalebarStyle: 'line',
                    scalebarUnit: 'dual'
                }
            },
            locateButton: {
                include: true,
                id: 'locateButton',
                type: 'domNode',
                path: 'gis/dijit/LocateButton',
                srcNodeRef: 'locateButton',
                options: {
                    map: true,
                    publishGPSPosition: true,
                    highlightLocation: true,
                    useTracking: true,
                    geolocationOptions: {
                        maximumAge: 0,
                        timeout: 15000,
                        enableHighAccuracy: true
                    }
                }
            },
            overviewMap: {
                include: true,
                id: 'overviewMap',
                type: 'map',
                path: 'esri/dijit/OverviewMap',
                options: {
                    map: true,
                    attachTo: 'bottom-right',
                    color: '#0000CC',
                    height: 100,
                    width: 125,
                    opacity: 0.30,
                    visible: false
                }
            },
            homeButton: {
                include: true,
                id: 'homeButton',
                type: 'domNode',
                path: 'esri/dijit/HomeButton',
                srcNodeRef: 'homeButton',
                options: {
                    map: true,
                    extent: new Extent({
                        xmin: -180,
                        ymin: -85,
                        xmax: 180,
                        ymax: 85,
                        spatialReference: {
                            wkid: 4326
                        }
                    })
                }
            },
            legend: {
                include: true,
                id: 'legend',
                type: 'titlePane',
                path: 'esri/dijit/Legend',
                title: 'Legend',
                open: false,
                position: 0,
                options: {
                    map: true,
                    legendLayerInfos: true
                }
            },
            layerControl: {
                include: true,
                id: 'layerControl',
                type: 'titlePane',
                path: 'gis/dijit/LayerControl',
                title: 'Layers',
                open: false,
                position: 0,
                options: {
                    map: true,
                    layerControlLayerInfos: true,
                    separated: true,
                    vectorReorder: true,
                    overlayReorder: true
                }
            },
            bookmarks: {
                include: true,
                id: 'bookmarks',
                type: 'titlePane',
                path: 'gis/dijit/Bookmarks',
                title: 'Bookmarks',
                open: false,
                position: 2,
                options: 'config/bookmarks'
            },
            find: {
                include: true,
                id: 'find',
                type: 'titlePane',
                canFloat: true,
                path: 'gis/dijit/Find',
                title: 'Find',
                open: false,
                position: 3,
                options: 'config/find'
            },
            draw: {
                include: true,
                id: 'draw',
                type: 'titlePane',
                canFloat: true,
                path: 'gis/dijit/Draw',
                title: 'Draw',
                open: false,
                position: 4,
                options: {
                    map: true,
                    mapClickMode: true
                }
            },
            measure: {
                include: true,
                id: 'measurement',
                type: 'titlePane',
                canFloat: true,
                path: 'gis/dijit/Measurement',
                title: 'Measurement',
                open: false,
                position: 5,
                options: {
                    map: true,
                    mapClickMode: true,
                    defaultAreaUnit: units.SQUARE_MILES,
                    defaultLengthUnit: units.MILES
                }
            },
            print: {
                include: true,
                id: 'print',
                type: 'titlePane',
                canFloat: true,
                path: 'gis/dijit/Print',
                title: 'Print',
                open: false,
                position: 6,
                options: {
                    map: true,
                    printTaskURL: 'https://utility.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Utilities/PrintingTools/GPServer/Export%20Web%20Map%20Task',
                    copyrightText: 'Copyright 2014',
                    authorText: 'Me',
                    defaultTitle: 'Viewer Map',
                    defaultFormat: 'PDF',
                    defaultLayout: 'Letter ANSI A Landscape'
                }
            },
            directions: {
                include: true,
                id: 'directions',
                type: 'titlePane',
                path: 'gis/dijit/Directions',
                title: 'Directions',
                open: false,
                position: 7,
                options: {
                    map: true,
                    mapRightClickMenu: true,
                    options: {
                        routeTaskUrl: 'http://sampleserver3.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Network/USA/NAServer/Route',
                        routeParams: {
                            directionsLanguage: 'en-US',
                            directionsLengthUnits: units.MILES
                        },
                        active: false //for 3.12, starts active by default, which we dont want as it interfears with mapClickMode
                    }
                }
            },
            editor: {
                include: true,
                id: 'editor',
                type: 'titlePane',
                path: 'gis/dijit/Editor',
                title: 'Editor',
                open: false,
                position: 8,
                options: {
                    map: true,
                    mapClickMode: true,
                    editorLayerInfos: true,
                    settings: {
                        toolbarVisible: true,
                        showAttributesOnClick: true,
                        enableUndoRedo: true,
                        createOptions: {
                            polygonDrawTools: ['freehandpolygon', 'autocomplete']
                        },
                        toolbarOptions: {
                            reshapeVisible: true,
                            cutVisible: true,
                            mergeVisible: true
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            streetview: {
                include: true,
                id: 'streetview',
                type: 'titlePane',
                canFloat: true,
                position: 9,
                path: 'gis/dijit/StreetView',
                title: 'Google Street View',
                options: {
                    map: true,
                    mapClickMode: true,
                    mapRightClickMenu: true
                }
            },
            help: {
                include: true,
                id: 'help',
                type: 'floating',
                path: 'gis/dijit/Help',
                title: 'Help',
                options: {}
            },
            disclaimer: {
                include: true,
                id: 'disclaimer',
                type: 'floating',
                path: 'gis/dijit/Disclaimer',
                title: 'Disclaimer',
                options: {
                    style: 'height:295px;width:375px;',
                    href: 'config/disclaimer.html'
                }
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: I notice that you have provided three answers to this question, and am not sure if you realized that you could have simply edited your original answer to revise it with the details that came out of the clarifications instead.  It is allowed to have more than one answer but, in this case, I think that is not the best course of action.

Comment: Thanks PolyGeo. I do know this and have done that in the past. Using the mobile app today it was a challenge to do that for this Q&As.